# How to force rerouting of a packet after return to netfilter from NFQUEUE

Tags: network-programming, netfilter

I have a caching application that runs in userspace.  Normally, it uses DPDK to interact with the NICs directly without kernel interaction, grabbing packets off of the wire, and either passing them through, generating a response from cache, or in some occasions blocking them.  It's transparent to the endpoints, and is written to work on raw packet data straight from the NIC. Notably, I'm not doing normal socket programming here - everything's handled at the packet level, without interaction with the TCP/IP stack.

For reasons that are long and boring, I wanted to add some NAT functionality. As a proof of concept, I was hoping to put a front end on my application using iptables/netfilter.  So I did the NAT parts with commands like these:

```
sudo iptables --table nat --append PREROUTING --in-interface seg1a  -j DNAT --to-destination $SERVERIP
sudo iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface seg1b -j MASQUERADE
sudo route add $SERVERIP seg1b
```

This works well for my purposes.  The clients now attach to an interface on my system, but their traffic gets redirected to the server.  I'm guaranteed that their traffic passes through my system, so all's good.

But to be useful as a cache, I need to be able to respond to some requests that I get from clients.  I had thought I could use NFQUEUE for this, with a small application that reads from the netfilter queue and passes packets to and from my application via IPC.  I used an iptables rule like this:

```
sudo iptables --table mangle --append FORWARD -j NFQUEUE
```

This works OK as long as my application doesn't respond to anything.  But when my cache attempts to respond to something from one of the endpoints, things go wrong.  The cache reverses all of the L2-4 headers, manages sequence and ack numbers, etc.  But the packets don't get back to the client.

I think what's happening is that routing decisions for the packet were made before it was sent to NFQUEUE.  So even though the cache returns something whose source and destination IP addresses are reversed, that's irrelevant for the routing of the packet.

I've tried a number of things to change the routing of my response packets, but nothing seems to work.  How does one go about changing the routing on a packet read from netfilter queues?  Failing that, is there a good way to just inject packets onto the wire from netfilter queues?  If that were doable, I could block the original request and then send the cache's reply as an entirely new thing.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: can you please to understand `I need to be able to respond to some requests that I get from clients and the packets don't get back to the client.`. Is the client running on your server using non-dpdk NIC? Is your requirement to respond to the client request comining on non DPDK NIC? If you are aware of client packet signature to which you need to reply, why not use eBPF or XDP to redirect to your DPDK cache application, then inject back to Kernel via DPDK-TAP interface?

Comment: The clients are elsewhere on the network.  I'm intercepting network traffic and responding to them.  I'm not using any DPDK interfaces because I would like to be able to use the existing iptables NAT functionality rather than write my own for this quick proof of concept, so there really isn't a DPDK-TAP interface to use.

Comment: So your current solution does not use any DPDK NIC interface. Not clear how the user space DPDK cache application gets packets if not DPDK-TAP. Is it DPDK-KNI? Second question, if the real intention is to send reply from specific request XDP eBPF would be better choice as it can access the tables and FIB from kernel. Sorry for the follow up as I am not able clearly understand the setup.

Comment: please ignore my previous comment, I have re-read multiple times to understand the problem. Your current setup is `NIC <==> iptables/netfilter <=  application reads from NFQUEUE and forwards via IPC => Caching userspace application`. Question is about `packets not getting forwarded after getting modified from caching application by reversing L2-4 headers, manages sequence and ack. numbers`. As discussed any tap interface from userspace with right dst-ip should get packet routed. But you suspect `routing is not considered`. Is this right?

Comment: If you are injecting back with IPC itself, can you please try injecting the modified packet via TAP interface. This should allow the routing FIB table in Linux to be accessed and the packet to be sent on the interface right?

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I came up with for this problem was to open a raw socket and feed it my pre-built packets.  Critically, you must create an iptables rule that matches your generated packets and tells netfilter not to do connection tracking.  Otherwise, netfilter sees the injected packets and thinks there's a connection collision.  It then does port forwarding, so the packets come out with a different port than you put in there!

I built the socket like this:

```
    sid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

Then, I turned on a couple of options (leaving failure handling out for brevity):

```
int one = 1;
const int *val = &one;
retval = setsockopt(sid, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof(one));    
retval = setsockopt(sid, SOL_SOCKET, SO_MARK, val, sizeof(one));
```

The first of these tells the kernel that I have the headers already, so no need to try and create them.  The second tells the kernel to put a mark value of 1 on every packet sent via the socket, which I can match against in routing or iptables rules.

Later, I built a destination address and used sendto() to send the packet:

```
retval = sendto(sid, pL3, len, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&daddr, sizeof(daddr));
```

Finally, I installed a rule telling netfilter not to do connection tracking on TCP packets marked with a 1.  Since I had added the sockopt above so that all of my generated packets had this mark, this worked well:

```
 sudo iptables -t raw -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m mark --mark 1 -j CT --notrack
```